# FFMpeg Unable to find suitable output format

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to capture a single image from my webcam using FFMpeg but the following command returns with an error. Any ideas?

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" -t 1 –r 25 c:\temp\image%d.jpg
```

Here is the text from the command line window.

```
C:\Users\User\Downloads\FFMPeg\ffmpeg-20150915-git-8e92462-win64-static\bin>f
fmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" -t 1 -r 25 c:\temp\image%d.jpg
ffmpeg version N-75287-g8e92462 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavcodec     57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavformat    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6.  3.100 /  6.  3.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Integrated Webcam':
  Duration: N/A, start: 417955.980000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 30 tbr,
10000k tbn, 30 tbc
[NULL @ 000000000304a5e0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ΓÇôr'
ΓÇôr: Invalid argument
```

Comment: complete command line and uncut console output please?

Comment: I have added the full console text.

Comment: That `ΓÇôr` seems a bit odd, what if you replace `c:\temp\image%d.jpg` with `out.avi` or something?

Comment: Thanks @LordNeckbeard, indeed the hyphen was incorrect!